# Predicting digits with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a python to recognize a 28x28 RGB picture for my sudoku program.

I jumped into keras and MNIST following the book "Deep Learning with Python, Second Edition" and the output of the models explained are quite high ~97% to 99%...So I thought they would be enough but when I plug in my own number file for the prediction, it is a complete disaster....Very far from 97% accuracy..

So I created my own database of numbers (instead of using MNIST) and given I have control of the input, the numbers are pretty well defined in the 28x28 matrix but I cannot make the model predict correctly. Below is the script for the model creation and the script for the prediction. I also added a few screenshots of my images so you have an idea how clean and precise they are. Still prediction is not even close to 90%.

I must be doing something wrong as it cannot be so difficult to predict the files I have. Can you help me understand what I am  doing wrong.
Thank you in advance...

```
#MODEL CREATION
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_mnist_model_3():
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(inputs)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.Flatten()(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

model_3 = get_mnist_model_3()
model_3.compile(optimizer="rmsprop",
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"])

callbacks_list_3 = [
    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor="val_loss",
        min_delta=0,
        patience=1,),
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath="checkpoint_3.keras",
        monitor="val_loss",
        save_best_only=True,)]

dataset_3 = image_dataset_from_directory(
    "/home/pi/Documents/AI_Keras/sdk_numbers",
    image_size=(28, 28),
    color_mode="grayscale",
    batch_size=1)

#Total 1391 batches of size 1
split1_qty = 973 #70%
split2_qty = 347 #25%
train_dataset_3 = dataset_3.take(split1_qty)
temp_dataset = dataset_3.skip(split1_qty)
validation_dataset_3 = temp_dataset.take(split2_qty)
test_dataset_3 = temp_dataset.skip(split2_qty)

history_3 = model_3.fit(train_dataset_3,
          epochs=10,
          callbacks=callbacks_list_3,
          validation_data=(validation_dataset_3))

test_metrics_3 = model_3.evaluate(test_dataset_3)
print("test_acc  _3: {0:.1%}  /#/  test_loss _3: {1:.1%}".format(test_metrics_3[1], test_metrics_3[0]))

history_dict_3 = history_3.history
loss_values_3 = history_dict_3["loss"]
val_loss_values_3 = history_dict_3["val_loss"]
acc_3 = history_dict_3["accuracy"]
val_acc_3 = history_dict_3["val_accuracy"]
epochs_3 = range(1, len(loss_values_3) + 1)

plt.plot(epochs_3, loss_values_3, "go", label="Training loss_3")
plt.plot(epochs_3, val_loss_values_3, "g", label="Validation loss_3")
plt.title("Training and validation loss")
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.clf()
plt.plot(epochs_3, acc_3, "go", label="Training acc_3")
plt.plot(epochs_3, val_acc_3, "g", label="Validation acc_3")
plt.title("Training and validation accuracy")
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

model_3.save('/home/pi/Documents/AI_Keras/model_3.keras')
print('Done')
```

MODEL INFERENCE

```
import random
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
import pathlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2 as cv

model_3 = keras.models.load_model('/home/pi/Documents/AI_Keras/model_3.keras')

dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    "/home/pi/Documents/AI_Keras/Numbers",
    image_size=(28, 28),
    color_mode="grayscale",
    batch_size=10)

data_dir = '/home/pi/Documents/AI_Keras/Numbers'
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
rest = list(data_dir.glob('rest/*'))

print('Target files :')
a = []
for i in range (9):
    aux = random.randint(1,len(rest))
    a.append(aux)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for i in range (9):
    print(rest[a[i]])
    image = cv.imread(str(rest[a[i]]))
    image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image1 = np.array(image.reshape(28 * 28).astype("float32") / 255)
    image1 = np.expand_dims(image1, axis=0)
    image2 = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    predictions_3 = model_3.predict(image2)
    pred= str(predictions_3.argmax())
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title(pred)
    plt.imshow(image)

plt.show()
print('Done')
```

[Result of inference - Note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW8UX.png) 
AND
[Example of Image files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch4VG.png)

Comment: Could you add the loss or accuracy curve of the training and validation set? The model declaration seems fine to me.

Comment: You mentioned you are using your own dataset instead of MNIST, are you normalizing the values? it might be that your pixel values are in RGB format (so they're integers up to 256).

Comment: Thank you so much. Based on the feedback I went back and found I had not normalized and vectorized my dataset. It is now working as expected. Thank you.